# Python is overlooking this section of code

Tags: python

I am trying to get python to loop a section of code by naming that piece of code and trying to loop it back when the else is called. But, I don't even have to put the code to loop in for python to overlook the defined code. It is almost like I made it invisible:

```
def main():                                                            from here

   weight = int(input("How much do you weigh?: "))
   unit = input("Lbs or Kgs?: ")

   if unit.upper() == ("KGS"):
      converted = weight * 2.2
      print("Your weight in pounds is: " + str(converted) + "pounds")
   elif unit.upper() == ("LBS"):
      converted = weight / 2.2
      print("Your weight in kilograms is: " + str(converted) + "pounds")
                                                                             to here
correct = input("Does This Look Correct? ")
if correct.upper() == "NO":
  print("Let's try again then")
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh: "))
  unit = input("Kgs or Lbs?: ")

  if unit.upper() == "KGS":
     converted = weight * 2.2
     print("Your weight in pounds is: " + str(converted) + " pounds")
  elif unit.upper() == ("LBS"):
     converted = weight / 2.2
     print("Your weight in kilos is: " + str(converted) + " kilograms")
else:
  print("Have A Great Day Then!")
```

Comment: You never call `main()`. Functions don't run unless they're called.

Answer (score 1):

Functions only run when they're called. You have to call `main()` in the loop.

```
while True:
    main()
    correct = input("Does this look correct? ")
    if correct.upper() == "NO":
        print("Let's try again then")
    else:
        print("Have a great day then!")
        break
```